# Using CosmoDb Table API with Azure Table Services and .NET Core

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

Given the older [Azure Storage NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) package is being broken up, it's not entirely clear from the documentation how you access Azure Table Storage from a .NET Core app.

There seems to be some conflicting information. According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet), the recommended way of access Table Storage is now with the CosmoDb Table API package, but that same article says it doesn't work with .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .net core, you should keep using the older [Azure Storage NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9639#issuecomment-395522546):

```
Adding .Net Core/standard support for Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table is on our roadmap. And
yes you should use `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' until .Net core, support is enabled 
for Azure Cosmos DB Table API.
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I’ve got an open issue with Azure Support on Twitter for this, so hopefully an engineer can at least provide some time scales...

Comment: Since it is by design, and will be implemented some time later, could you accept it by an answer? Thanks.